# Including dia2.h fails with C1083: Cannot open include file

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dia-sdk

The documentation for the [DIA SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/getting-started-debug-interface-access-sdk) claims that the header file is located at `include\dia2.h`. However, the following program fails to compile:

```cpp
#include <include\dia2.h>

int main() {}
```

The full error diagnostic is

> ```
> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'include\dia2.h': No such file or directory
> ```

What's the issue and how do I solve it?

Comment: #include "include\dia2.h"

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh The DIA SDK isn't set up by default. Using `#include "include\dia2.h"` fails in much the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DIA SDK isn't part of the platform SDK. Its artifacts aren't immediately available and must be explicitly introduced into the build system, like any old library.

For MSBuild-based systems, like Visual Studios, you'll want to navigate to *"VC++ Directories"* and add `$(VSInstallDir)DIA SDK\include` to *"Include Directories"*, or add

```xml
  <IncludePath>$(VSInstallDir)DIA SDK\include;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
```

to the respective items in the .vcxproj file. This has to be done for *"All Configurations"* and *"All Platforms"*.

When building from the command line, use the [`/I <dir>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories) compiler option. From a Visual Studio Command Prompt, the following will successfully build an object file:

```
cl /I "%VSINSTALLDIR%DIA SDK\include" main.cpp
```

Doing the above and changing the code to

```cpp
#include "dia2.h"

int main() {}
```

successfully compiles. This is following what the [Dia2dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/dia2dump-sample) sample does. The sample is installed into `%VSINSTALLDIR%DIA SDK\Samples\DIA2Dump`.